# Should the Citizen Patrol badge be grouped with Deputy and Marshal badge

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges, help-center, flagging-badges

On the [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=general&filter=all) page in HelpCenter in the section Moderation Badges, the **Citizen Patrol** batch is listed alone and not grouped with the **Deputy** and **Marshal** badge, that are also awarded for flagging.

Should it be grouped? The badges for editing (**Editor**, **Strunk & White**, **Copy Editor**) are grouped.

Or is the Citizen Patrol badge awarded for flagging no matter if the flag is helpful or not?

Comment: Yes. And while we're at it, please don't show tag badges as earned unless I have actually earned it.

Comment: Read the descriptions - raising a flag gives you `Citizen Patrol`, even if it is declined. The other two are for _helpful_ flags.

Comment: .... which is an adequate reflection on real-world Citizen Patrols, I suppose. :)

Comment: Yes it's not exactly the same (any flag vs helpful), but they're still "the flag badges" and should be grouped together because of that.

Comment: @Oded The Editor badge is grouped with Strunk & White, even though it's not exactly the same either.  I can edit my own post for Editor, but Strunk & White requires me to edit other people's posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are related enough that we're going to group them.